# ODI Import: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: garbage-collection, out-of-memory, oracle-data-integrator

i'm trying to import a large project in ODI with ODI Studio 12c. 
After 3 hours of import the process fails with the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at oracle.odi.ui.framework.adapter.DefaultAdapter.executeBackgroundTask(DefaultAdapter.java:636)
    at oracle.odi.ui.framework.UIFramework.executeBackgroundTask(UIFramework.java:452)
    at oracle.odi.ui.smartie.imp.ImportSmartWizard.runImportProcess(ImportSmartWizard.java:394)
    at oracle.odi.ui.smartie.imp.ImportSmartWizard.runImport(ImportSmartWizard.java:260)
    at oracle.odi.ui.smartie.imp.ImportSmartWizard.finished(ImportSmartWizard.java:205)
    at 
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:2694)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:203)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:405)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2004)
    at com.sunopsis.dwg.smartie.RunSmartImport.run(RunSmartImport.java:3264)
```

I increased the option
AddVMOption -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M to 
AddVMOption -XX:MaxPermSize=4096M

Any other suggestions?

Thank you so much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded)

Answer (score 1):

You can try `-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit`

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the size of the young/old generations, not the permanent generation.  Change the argument to -Xmx4096m (or similar).

The permanent generation contains all the reflective data of the virtual machine itself, such as class and method objects.  Your OOM exception is coming from an array copy so not related to the perm gen.